# Meteor and Ionic. Order of use

Tags: javascript, meteor, ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile application using Meteor.  I have found a little difficult to make the UI controls to look as the mobile apps do (scrolls, checkbox, buttons).  Searching the web I have found Ionic as a help for mobile like UI.

My question is: Should I continue developing my app with METEOR not taking special care so far of UI, and deploy IONIC at the end of my development?  Or IONIC could make interaction different between client and server so I should learn and adapt IONIC now?

My app requires a server side which process a lot of app logic, thats why I'm using Meteor.  If there are better options for front end Framework instead of Ionic, please suggest them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ruben, can you update your question to explicitly ask for an answer that is not opinion based? The current question is asking for an opinion on front end frameworks.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I think my question enquire about best practices of the industry and not opinions.

Comment: @Ruben If you use React you can integrate Meteor and Ionic with this library I developed: https://github.com/pors/reactionic/. Demo is here: http://pors.github.io/reactionic/#demo